# Lat/lgn return 0

Tags: java, android, google-maps, gps, geolocation

I'm currently working on a project for school.  I have to use location service.  I have a marker problem.  I can locate myself on the map with a small point from google (I think), but the marker is always on 0,0.  If my logic is good, the `getLatitude()` and the `getLongitude()` return `NULL`.  I've follow a tutorial for the code.

```js
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    GPSTracker gps;
    //ImageItem imgItem;
    double lat;
    double longi;
    double latitude;
    double longitude;
    String adresse;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        laCreation();
    }

    public void laCreation() {
        gps = new GPSTracker(MapsActivity.this);

        if (gps.canGetLocation()==true) {

            latitude = gps.getLatitude();
            longitude = gps.getLongitude();
            lat = latitude;
            longi =  longitude;
        } else {
            gps.showSettingsAlert();
        }
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        mMap = mapFragment.getMap();
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
       
        }
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, longi);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(position).title("Vous : "+ latitude + ","+longitude +"," +adresse));//new LatLng(lat,longi)
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(position));
    }
    
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {}
}
```

Here is my GPSTracker :

```js
public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

    private final Context context;

    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;
    boolean canGetLocation = false;

    Location location;

    double latitude;
    double longitude;

    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10;  //10m avant update gps
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 2000;   //2 sec avant uptade gps

    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    public GPSTracker(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        getLocation();
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
            } else {
                this.canGetLocation = true;
                onLocationChanged(location);


                if (isGPSEnabled) {                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            if (latitude ==0){showSettingsAlert();}
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            if (latitude ==0){showSettingsAlert();}
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return location;
    }

    public void stopUsingGPS() {
        if (locationManager != null) {
            }
            locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }


    public double getLatitude(){

        if(location != null){
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }
        return latitude;
    }

    public double getLongitude(){
        if(location != null){

            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }
        return longitude;
    }

    public boolean canGetLocation(){

        return this.canGetLocation;
    }

    public void showSettingsAlert(){
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS en cours de configuration");
        alertDialog.setMessage("GPS non valide. Voulez-vous aller dans le menu de configuration?");
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Configuration", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Annuler", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

I'm French, sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 0):

You should utilize method

```
   @Override 
   public void onLocationChanged(Location location) { 
        Log.i(TAG, location.getLatitude()+"-"+longitude = location.getLongitude());
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
    }
```

for getting latitude and longitude. First time it will get definitely call and then it will be call and then as soon as location gets changed.

If you force fully asking for latti and longi their are chances OS is not having anything s it would return 0,0.

One way more ask for last known location using GoogleFuseLocationApi

```
 public class SpotRecognistionService extends Service {


private static final String TAG = SpotRecognistionService.class.getSimpleName();
public static final String NOTIFICATION = "location.track.services.receiver";


//Google Api Client for Location 
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;


// private Location mLastLocation; 
private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
private GPSLocationListener gpsLocationListener;


@Override 
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null; 
} 


protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() { 
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(gpsLocationListener)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(gpsLocationListener)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API) 
            .build(); 
} 


@Override 
public void onCreate() { 
    super.onCreate(); 
    Log.i(TAG, "Service creating");


    gpsLocationListener = new GPSLocationListener();
    buildGoogleApiClient(); 


    //Connect  to get Location 
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
} 


@Override 
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onStartCommand()");
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
} 


@Override 
public void onDestroy() { 
    super.onDestroy(); 
    Log.i(TAG, "Service destroying");
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected())
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
} 


private class GPSLocationListener implements LocationListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {


    @Override 
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {


        if (location != null) {
        //Update Result 
        publishResults(location.toString(), 1);
    } 


    private void publishResults(String lat_Long, int result) {
       Log.i(TAG, lat_Long);
    } 


    @Override 
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(10000);


        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    } 


    @Override 
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        reConnect(); 
    } 


    @Override 
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        reConnect(); 
    } 


    public void reConnect() { 
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null && !mGoogleApiClient.isConnected())
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    } 
}
```

}